# Detect if a tab/download has finished loading in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, grails

I'm generating a pdf on Grails using the following pattern:

> **Optional Step:**
>   The user will choose either he wants to download the *.pdf or to open it on another tab, the default is to open it to another tab.

**Main Step:**

1. Click the <kbd>Generate Report</kbd> button.
2. The button will change its text to <kbd>Generating Report, please
   wait...</kbd>
3. It will run a block of JavaScript something like this:

   ```
   var generate = "<sample url>"

   // some amazing processing goes here that appends data to the
   // query string.

   window.open(generate,'_blank');
   ```
4. Then it will open a new tab (or start downloading, depending on the option he had chosen).

   > Note: The opened tab is not an ordinary html markup, but rather a `*.pdf` that is rendered on a browser tab.
5. The tab (or the download) will load for at least five seconds to 1 minute or so.
6. The pdf on that tab will finish loading and the user can now navigate the pdf (scroll down, save, print etc); or if it is a download, he can now open that file.
7. The button on the calling tab will change its text to <kbd>Report
   has been generated</kbd>.

I already generated the reports successfully (both the new tab and the download approach), however my problem is *I don't know how to detect if that tab has finished loading*, and I cannot do step 7. Can anyone help me how to implement this?

Comment: Have a look to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Spring Websocket](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-websocket) to send the status of the generation back to the JavaScript, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var socket = new SockJS("${createLink(uri: '/stomp')}");
        var client = Stomp.over(socket);

        client.connect({}, function () {
            client.subscribe("/topic/generatePdf", function (message) {
                console.log(message);
                $("#bnt").value(JSON.parse(message.body));
            });
        });
        $("#bnt").click(function() {
            client.send("/app/generatePdf", {}, JSON.stringify({
                'type': 'foo',
                'id':2
            }));
        });
    });
</script>
```